# Arraylist Postfix Validation

Tags: arraylist

Can someone help me with this problem?

They gave me conditions on how will i do this kind of problem.
These are the conditions:
1.Scanner
2.Arraylist
3.Input seperated by space
4.If the input is integer(ex. any number) then the ctr will be ++, if operator(*,/,+,-), the ctr will be --
if the input is not integer or operator, Its invalid input.
5. Continue? Y/N at the end.

What is the best approach for this? Can someone help me pls. It will be appreciated so much. Thanks!
(Im new to java, and i want to learn)

Comment: draw a flowchart and start your coding what you know. If you got struck, come and ask here. Be specific.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan
Thanks for replying. I already coded but im not satiesfied. My program just accept one-digit number. All i want is to accept any integer( ex. 2-digit etc) and seperated by space when i input.
Ill post the code below.

Comment: why don't you try for few google searches? These are very basic and primitive actions.

Comment: I googled but i dont understand all so that i tried to ask here hoping someone can help me in easiest way to achieve it. Im just a beginner but willing to learn more

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("Enter Postfix Notation: ");
            notation =input.nextLine();

```
    if(notation.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*"))
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input sorry.");
    }

    else if(notation.charAt(0) <= 0 || notation.charAt(1) >= 9)
    {
     for(int x = 0; x < notation.length(); x++)
     {

        list.add(notation.charAt(x));
        if(list.get(x).equals('/') || list.get(x).equals('*')||list.get(x).equals('-')|| list.get(x).equals('+'))
        {
                 ctr--;

        }
         else if(list.get(x) <= 0 || list.get(x) >= 9)
                 ctr++;

         }
     }
    else if(notation.charAt(0) == '/' || notation.charAt(0) == '*' || notation.charAt(0) == '-' || notation.charAt(0) == '+' ||
            notation.charAt(1) == '/' || notation.charAt(1) == '*' || notation.charAt(1) == '-' || notation.charAt(1) == '+')
            System.out.println("The first two numbers should be operands");

    if(ctr == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("The postfix is valid.");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The postfix is invalid.");
    }
```

Comment: use subString() and use a regex for condition for 'first two number should be operands'